# How do you hide/restore a toolbar when switching from/to a page of a QStackedWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, toolbar

The application I'm writing has several different pages that I switch between with a `QStackedWidget`. I want to have a toolbar that is shown only when a certain page is active.

My initial plan was to simply call `addToolbar()` from that page, but it appears that *only* a `QMainWindow` has the `addToolbar()` method. So instead, I create the toolbar as a member of the page. My `QMainWindow` holds the `QStackedWidget` and calls `addToolbar(self.page.toolbar)` when I switch to that page and `removeToolbar(self.page.toolbar)` when I switch away from it.

In the documentation for `removeToolbar()` it says: Removes the toolbar from the main window layout and hides it. Note that the toolbar is not deleted.

But it certainly seems as if the toolbar is being deleted. When I start the program, the toolbar is hidden as I want it to be. When I switch to the page, `addToolbar()` is called and the toolbar is displayed. When I leave the page, `removeToolbar()` is called and it is hidden again. So far so good.

The problem is that any following time that I go to the page, the toolbar is never shown again, even though `addToolbar()` is being called each time.

Am I adding a toolbar that has been hidden? How can I unhide it?

Or, alternatively, is it possible to tie a `QToolBar` to an arbitrary widget instead of only a `QMainWindow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `addToolBar` and `removeToolBar` I used `QToolBar`'s `toggleViewAction()`.

In widget for the page where I want the toolbar, I create the toolbar and set it's toggleViewAction to false, then trigger it. That makes the toolbar initially hidden.

```
    self.toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar(self)

    #add the toolbar to the main window
    self.parent().addToolBar(self.toolbar)

    #start hidden
    self.toolbar.toggleViewAction().setChecked(False)
    self.toolbar.toggleViewAction().trigger()
```

Then whenever I switch to or from the page, I trigger `toggleViewAction()` again:

```
def changeMode(self, page_num):
    #leaving page
    if self.page_stack.currentIndex() == PageEnum.PAGE_WITH_TOOLBAR:
        self.tb_page.toolbar.toggleViewAction().trigger()
        None

    #entering page
    if page_num == PageEnum.PAGE_WITH_TOOLBAR:
        self.tb_page.toolbar.toggleViewAction().trigger()
        None

    self.page_stack.setCurrentIndex(page_num)
```

I feel like a fool for finding the answer so quickly by browsing the QToolBar documentation, but hopefully someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

QToolBar::show() must be called, after you call addToolBar(toolBar). cpp style code goes like:

```
void setToolBarVisible(bool visibility)
{
    if(visibility)
    {
        addToolBar(toolBar);
        toolBar->show();
    }
    else
    {
        removeToolBar(toolBar);
    }
}
```